# nested viewmodel design best practices

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am not really new to MVVM but I am not familiar with the known supporting frameworks such as mvvm light, and what design/best practices those enforce. I have 3 views with corresponding viewmodels. Assume the xaml looks like this:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="view1">
        <ns:view2></ns:view2>
    </UserControl>

    <UserControl x:Class="view2">
        <ns:view3></ns:view3>
    </UserControl>

    <UserControl x:Class="view3">

    </UserControl>
```

now how should the viewmodels be related? One approach is this:

```
class viewmodel1 {
    viewmodel2 _member;
}

class viewmodel2 {
    viewmodel3 _member;
}

class viewmodel3 {

}
```

Now I see that I just created a strong class coupling by using above approach. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would structure my view model classes as you have... I believe most MVVM developers would. That's because we generally use one view model to one view, so there really aren't too many options as to where to put the child view models.

> Now I see that I just created a strong class coupling by using above approach

Have you ever seen an MVVM application where the views are not coupled with the view models? Surely, by the nature of MVVM where we generally use one view model to one view, they're always coupled. However, this is not a problem because these are not reusable data classes.

Even in the rare case that we wanted to replace our UI layer, the view models would probably disappear along with the views, depending on what was replacing them. Think about it... `INotifyPropertyChange` implementations and `ICommand` instances would not be required in a WinForms application, or even a web application.

Therefore, I would advise that there is absolutely no problem with organising your views/view models in this way.

Comment: Thanks for input, I might go with this approach after all! with 'strong class coupling' I just meant the relationship between the viewmodel instances, that a viewmodel instance has another viewmodel instance as a class member.